# In Emacs Lisp, how do you get a single hash key?

Tags: lisp, hashtable, elisp

The problem I am trying to solve is to find the fewest number of subtrees in a non-directed graph where each node is in a subtree.

My algorithm is the following:

```
make a hash as follows
     key= each node, 
     value= all nodes directly accessible from the key node
   if a node has no edges it still has a key/value pair in the hash
   each edge will be represented twice, once each direction
loop until hash is empty
  get any hash key/value pair
  save the value to the working-list
  remove the key/value from the hash
  in a loop until the working-list is empty
     (when (gethash (car working-list) hash)
        concatenate value to the end of the working-list
        (remhash (car working-list) hash))
     (pop working-list)
  When the loop is finished you have removed all nodes and edges in a single subtree from the hash.
  Increment number of subtrees.
end loop until the hash is empty.
report number of subtrees
```

Here's the code:

```
(defun count-subtrees (hash)
; hash
;     key= each node, 
;     value= all nodes directly accessible from the key node
;   if a node has no edges it still has a key/value pair in the hash
;   each edge will be represented twice, once each direction

(let ((number-of-trees 0))
  (while (setf key (anykey-in-hash hash))     ; this is where I need any key in the hash
    (setf working-list (gethash key hash))
    (remhash key hash)
    (while (gethash (car working-list) hash)
      (setf working-list (append working-list 
                                 (gethash (car working-list hash))))
      (remhash (car working-list) hash)
      (pop working-list))
    (incf number-of-trees))
  number-of-trees))
```

I don't want to iterate over keys, I want to get just one.

NOTES:

Thank you all for responding. I am directing these comments to you.

An editor changed my question, adding the word "randomly". I don't care if it is random or not. The response:

```
(defun anykey-in-hash (hash-table)
    (block nil
       (maphash (lambda (k v) (return (values k v)))
```

is a perfect solution.

I inadvertently used 'while' (which I got from Paul Graham's book) without defining it. I hope it didn't confuse anyone.

I also used setf instead of let to define variables. Stupid mistake, I would never really do that.

Initially I have a list of all of the keys. But during the algorithm the key/value pairs get deleted. That is why I need to get any one left.

I am also using working-list as a list. working-list contains some of the nodes in a subtree. All of those nodes (and their children* and their children's children...) need to be removed from the hash. Appending to this list was to simplify the code. In a real application I would use some other data structure, probably a list of lists. But I felt that doing so here would add complexity without adding anything to the meaning of the question.

*When I say children, I mean use the node as a key to the hash, the value is a list of the children.

Comment: appending to the end of a list is not very speedy, especially if the list is very long...

Comment: *I inadvertently used 'while' (which I got from Paul Graham's book) without defining it* : what shall we do with the tags? keep emacs-lisp or change to common-lisp?

Comment: I don't care if it is "Emacs Lisp". Someone else changed the question from "Lisp"

Answer (score 3):

You are setting global variables without declaring them beforehand, which is not portable and generally unsafe due to side-effects; prefer let bindings.

As for getting "random" keys, you can simply implement `anykey-in-hash` like this:

```
(defun anykey-in-hash (hash-table)
  (block nil
    (maphash (lambda (k v) (return (values k v)))
             hash-table)))
```

The order of elements stored in a hash table depends on the implementation, so `maphash` will iterate over entries in an arbitrary (yet probably deterministic) order. If you really need to have a *random* order, i.e. an order which can change with different invocations of the function with the same arguments, you have to collect the keys and pick one randomly.

In your example, it seems you only need to compute the list of keys once, not at every iteration of the while loop. I'd personally get all keys in a list, *shuffle* it once, then *pop* elements from it as needed.

I originally though the code was in Common Lisp. In CL, the [Alexandria library](https://common-lisp.net/project/alexandria/draft/alexandria.html) defines `shuffle` (and `random-elt`), as well as `hash-table-keys` (or `hash-table-alist` if you need both the key and the value).

In Emacs Lisp, you can easily implement `hash-table-keys` with `maphash` too (you push the key in front of a list from inside the function called by maphash). If you have Emacs 24.4, you can  `(require 'subr-x)` and call `get-hash-keys`. Shuffling can be done like in CL, you could adapt the algorithm from alexandria (https://gitlab.common-lisp.net/alexandria/alexandria/blob/master/sequences.lisp#L90), knowing that you only care about the case where the argument is a list.

Comment: The code uses `while`, so I think it might be elisp rather than cl (the answer should still work, but no Alexandria).